# Java Buttons not working

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jbutton, japplet

so in my program by buttons aren't working. I have it where if they're pressed they change a few variables which in turn change the label of a text. As near as i can tell the variables won't add when the button is pressed. I can't figure out whats wrong, but then again I am new to Java so...

Anyways here's my code:

```
    import javax.swing.JApplet;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
    import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


    public class qa extends JApplet {

        int y=0;
        int x=0;
        int q=0;


        /**
         * Create the applet.
         */
        public qa() {
            getContentPane().setLayout(null);

            JButton btnYes = new JButton("YES");
            btnYes.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    y+=1;
                    q+=1;
                }
            });
            btnYes.setBounds(135, 220, 85, 42);
            getContentPane().add(btnYes);

            JButton btnNo = new JButton("NO");
                btnNo.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    x+=1;
                    q+=1;
                }
            });
            btnNo.setBounds(230, 220, 85, 42);
            getContentPane().add(btnNo);

            JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Do you like pizza?");
            lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 97, 450, 50);
            getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
            if (q>=1)
            {
                lblNewLabel.setText("Really?");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Define "not working."

Comment: Sorry, I mean when I press the button it won't add 1 to the variables y and q and x. Like the buttons dont even register the clicks

Comment: See [How to Make Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html) for the proper way to create an applet. Also read the sections on Using Layout Managers, and How to Use Buttons. The tutorial will provided you with the basics for using Swing.

Answer (score 3):

1. don't to use NullLayout
2. MouseListener isn't proper Listener for JButton, all MouseEvents are implemented in JButtons API and correctly
3. add and to use Swing Action, resp. ActionListener for JButton

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working fine. Only your `if (q>=1)` is not related to any listener action. Here are pointers.

1. Move your JLabel outside of your constructor.
2. Put `lblNewLabel.setText("YES Really?");` in one of your `mouseClicked()` method.

   ```
       @Override
       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
               y+=1;
               q+=1;
               if (q>2)
                   lblNewLabel.setText("YES Really?");
               System.out.println("YES: " + y + " q :" + q);
           }
       });
   ```